# Raspbian JavaFX VERY VERY SLOW

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi, executable-jar, javafxports

Hello Stackoverflow Community!

I am facing a problem,
when I want to execute my self-written JavaFX runnable Jar file program (it is a Chess game).

When I execute the program it needs about ten seconds to start.
After the start, when I want to select a piece or the menu items there are two possible options:

1. The Gui freezes completely after startup
2. I may click on a piece and it needs around 5 sec. to select it and when I want to hover (no self-written event) on the JavaFX menubar, the PI freezes for about 5 sec. and then displays the blue hover color.

I have a Raspberry PI 3.

I have currently installed the Java Environment: ,,openjdk version "1.8.0_40-internal" (`$ java -version`)

I added manually the JavaFX files (they are not included in this openjdk version) as it is mentioned at:[Gluonhq](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/) -section 2.1.4

I run the Jar file with: `java -jar Chess.jar` -> Chess.jar is jar file

The game runs without these errors on Linux Mint (openjdk version "1.8.0_131") and Windows 10.

I don´t know what is the source of the problem. Maybe JavaFX on the PI is simply not a good idea?

Anyway thanks for the help,

Alex

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possibly related to [this bug report](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/issues/90/unnecessary-creation-of-font_map-for-every)

Comment: Have you tried running a recent Oracle JDK on your Pi? Have you run a regular JavaFX sample on your Pi, and if so, how it behaves? As already stated above, without code or stacktraces we can't really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your quick answers and suggestions, but today I found the solution (tldr; including images of the meeples lead to exceptions, which lead to a bad performance. Removing the images improved the performance):

@Joe C - with my next question I will specify the problem more clearly ;)

@sillyfly - no but thx. for your answer

@Josê - Yes I tried. The first program I used gave me the same bug, but today I tried another self-written one -> this one worked fine -> see below

The problem was that the PI couldn't render my Meeples (they were basically images). I found this out using the stack trace of the PI. Two days ago I couldn´t access the stack trace, due to an impossibility of exiting the game, now I developed an exit function, and here goes the stack trace. It showed me, that there is a null pointer at `com.sun.prism.impl.BaseGraphics.drawTexture(BaseGraphics.java:4000)` - this is for rendering Images (as far as I know).

Today I removed my meeple images. I don´t know why the PI can´t render these images but it works fine now :)

-Alex